Problem with sending a reference list of Git repository (from info/refs) to client from custom server backend
I'm trying to write a custom HTTP server backend from scratch in C for Linux. And I need it also for hosting my Git repositories and managing Git-related requests (clone, push, pull, etc.). And I decided to use "git-http-backend" as a CGI program for handling responses with data needed by clients. All the global variables are handled and tested correctly.
When I try to send git clone http://<ip-of-host-pc>:8080/git/<project_dir> to a PC with server, I see that everything works fine and the "git-http-backend" returns me HTTP header (without code and HTTP protocol version), code of start of reference list (001e# service=git-upload-pack) and some references (SHA-1 + relative path), without the magic 0000 code.
First of all I send code (200 OK) and HTTP protocol version requered to the socket. After that I send a buffer with data returned by "git-http-backend" and finish everything with sending 0000 to the client. And nothing happens... As I know, it should send another request with the POST HTTP method. But only the infinite loop is encountered inside read while listening to the socket. I also tried to send 0x06 ("ACK") to the client separately, but nothing changes. If I quickly restart the backend, it would receive next request, but the client's git will write "fatal: git fetch-pack: expected ACK/NAK, got a flush packet" to console. Where is my mistake?
I am using socket, bind, accept, read, write and select in my code. And I remember about that every HTTP header's line should end with \r\n.
